# PHP inside another PHP - What I can do

Tags: php

I want to make this work, but I don't know how:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 999999 );

function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {

    $content = str_replace
    ('<h3>', '<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">click here</a><h3>',        $content,);

    return $content;
}
```

where

```
 echo $url;
```

is custom post field called url.

Comment: How does URL get into the PHP? if it's $_POST then you can do: '<a href="' . $_POST['url'] . '">click here</a><h3>'

Comment: What is the question??? What doesn't work? And what does `add_filter()`?

Answer (score 3):

This is a string:

```
'<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">click here</a><h3>'
```

If you know `$url` (and you do) you don't need to `echo` it. You can just add it with, for instance, string concatenation. try this.

```
'<a href="'.$url.'">click here</a><h3>'
```

Comment: This doesn't work :( It will not generate url so result is
<a href>click here</a><h3>

Comment: Well, obviously if you do not add anything to `$url` it will be empty, but this is how you do "php inside another php".

Comment: I am using <?php $url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'url', true); ?> in loop, but there this isnt working :/

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something important, just put the variable in the string:

```
$content = str_replace('<h3>', '<a href="'.$url.'">click here</a><h3>', $content,);
```

You'll need to send `$url` to the function too, or make it a global variable.

Have a read up on string concatenation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

change `'<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">click here</a><h3>'` to `'<a href="'.$url.'">click here</a><h3>'`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you're doing it wrong. This way you would either need eval() later, or one (or more) global variables - both is evil.

Build a class, feed it all needed variables, and do str_replace/preg_replace/whatever after that. Or use one of the many template engines.